# Duplicate column name with bitcoin inputs and outpus

Tags: google-bigquery, bitcoin

So the inputs and outputs bot have the attribute addresses by default.
How can i analyze both and put it on a data frame?

When i run this on the google online sql editor it says duplicate name error

```
SELECT `hash`, outp.addresses, inp.addresses
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions` , UNNEST(outputs) AS outp, UNNEST(inputs) AS inp
#WHERE '15rc854gtVwYCU22piKzgo6dnPQscWuFaz' IN UNNEST(outp.addresses) OR '15rc854gtVwYCU22piKzgo6dnPQscWuFaz' IN UNNEST(inp.addresses)
```

I expect the output to be just a table with 3 columns (hash of transaction, inputs and outputs addresses) where the address is in either one of them

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, it is easily fixed by just adding an alias such as

SELECT `hash`, outp.addresses AS out_addr, inp.addresses AS in_addr